# What we will call a Poisson process with random mean?

Tags: random-variables, poisson-process

Suppose I have a random number $v$ distributed as
$$v \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$$
now I have another random process $y$ which is given as
$$y\sim \operatorname{Poisson}(v)$$
I want to know what we call such Poisson process and is there some literature available on the same?

Comment: It looks to me as if you can say that $y$ is a discrete random variable with support on the non-negative integers and  $\mathbb E[y]=\lambda$.  But $y$ does not have a Poisson distribution: for example $\mathbb P(y=0) >e^{-\lambda}$.  So I suspect the distribution of $y$ does not have a common name.  Incidentally there is a difference between a *Poisson process* and a *Poisson distribution*

Comment: @Henry  does a Poisson process with random mean exist?

Comment: There is a notion of a doubly stochastic Poisson process, or a Cox process, which is a nonhomogeneous Poisson process in which the time-dependent intensity is itself a stochastic process. Perhaps that is what you are thinking of?